# Swift remove aspect ratio constraint

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, aspect-ratio

Is there a way to remove an aspect ratio constraint?

For example

```
let aspectRatio = messageImage.constraint(withIdentifier: "aspectRatio")
aspectRatio?.isActive = false
```

I need to keep all constraints of the object but remove just the aspect ratio

[image]

Something in this nature...

Comment: Well, when you run it do you see any of evidence of it being removed?

Comment: No. But is .isActive the porper way to do it?

Comment: I suggest `removeConstraint` instead.

Comment: Simple delete constraint from Storyboard

Comment: I need to remove it while the app is running

Comment: Why don't you connect the constraint with a `IBOutlet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a reference of the `imageView` and have given the constraint an identifier.
In your case, you have named the constraint with the identifier: `aspectRatio`.

So for the above, you can do this:

```
//Get constraints filtered against a user-defined identifier
let filteredConstraints = imageView.constraints.filter { 
    $0.identifier == "aspectRatio"
}

//Get the first constraint (...as per your case)
let aspectRatio = filteredConstraints.first

//Deactivate it
aspectRatio?.isActive = false
```

---

#### Extension Solution

To improve this further, you can extend `UIView` as:

```
extension UIView {

    func constraint(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
        let filteredConstraints = self.constraints.filter {
            $0.identifier == identifier            
        }

        return filteredConstraints.first
    }

}
```

and now you can finally do what you initially wanted, i.e:

```
let aspectRatio = imageView.constraint(withIdentifier: "aspectRatio")
aspectRatio?.isActive = false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an IBOutlet of the constraint and then set isActive to false in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func removeConstraint(_ constraint: NSLayoutConstraint)` method to remove a constraint added.

It is also mentioned that, This method will be deprecated in a future release and should be avoided.  Instead set NSLayoutConstraint's active property to NO.